# Product URL and Title not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem getting the URL to display on a contact form submission. I am using contact form 7 and it used to display till a few months ago but suddenly it stopped.

```
<?php
get_header();
if (isset($_GET['product_id']) && $_GET['product_id']) {
    $product = get_post((int) $_GET['product_id']);
    echo '<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#contact-message-area").html("Re: '.$product->post_title.'\n");
            $(".focus_textarea").hide();
            $("#enquiry-product").html("<a href=\''.get_permalink($_GET['product_id']).'\'>'.$product->post_title.'</a>");
    });
    </script>';
}?>
```

Above is the php code

```
<div style="display">[textarea product id:enquiry-product]</div>
```

Above is contact form code. I'm unable to understand what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error message in your JavaScript console?

Comment: @ChrisHaas There is one error -  Found 2 elements with non-unique id but i dont think they are related to my main query above. The above code was working till 2 months ago but suddenly stopped idk how. People used to go to Product A -> Click on Contact us -> I used to get URL and Page Title in my inbound reply. But now it doesnt show up

Comment: Is there something wrong with my contact form code?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the comments of the question that you get this error:

***"There is one error - Found 2 elements with non-unique id".***

That means that more than 1 HTML elements have the same id thus resulting in the error above. An id must be unique and only be used by one HTML element within the page.

Rename all the id attributes that are the same to be unique or use the class attribute instead.

W3Schools reference for the id attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

W3Schools reference for the class attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Comment: ```[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #searchform:  <form role=​"search" method=​"get" id=​"searchform" action=​"/​">​<input type=​"button" class=​"search_pro_submit" value>​<div class=​"search-detail">​<input type=​"text" name=​"s" placeholder=​"Product Search" class=​"search_pro">​<input type=​"submit" class=​"search_mobile_submit" value=​"GO">​</div>​</form>​```

Comment: @vjai I think changing the above would solve the issue. Or can you share your complete code so we can see if there are any other issues?

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/5gqNzD) Link to the contact form

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/5M0AV3) link to php code

Comment: @vjai I don't really see anything with an id attribute in your HTML code. This is confusing :/

Comment: The JavaScript errors were for the Search Button on top of the webpage so basically no javascript errors for the contact form code. Any clues? Is it something to do with the php code?

Comment: @vjai Is `product_id` defined?

Comment: Yes. So when a user clicks on contact us on Product 'A', he is taken to a URL - /contact-us/?product_id=xxxx. Each product has a different number(xxxx example 6631, 5542, etc). I tried the dynamic text plug-in for contact form 7 but it was displaying the URL of contact page and not the URL of the product page